# React component testing: is "enzyme" to test class component and "testing-library" is more to functional component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-component, react-testing-library

I'm struggling to test simple component (functional) that by changing input value should change var in component state, by onChange event.
Seems like as the state and functions are encapsulated in the component, testing-library is more suitable.
Make sense?
Is there any rules/guidelines for when to use which?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It goes against the principles of React Testing Library to be asserting on implementation details such as a components' state.

Instead, the library recommends you to write tests that closely resemble how the user will interact with your code.

From the [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles):

> We try to only expose methods and utilities that encourage you to write tests that closely resemble how your web pages are used.

---

> Is there any rules/guidelines for when to use which?

This can be a bit of a subjective topic and might greatly vary depending on which team you work on.

Personally, I switched from using only Enzyme(specifically `shallow` rendering) to using only React Testing Library, and this is what happened:

- It improved my developer experience as I feel the tests became way easier to maintain when the code implementation changes.
- I am more confident with the tests since they now resemble more how the software is actually used.
- Tests are easier to read and more intuitive. Think of `clicking this button should display that message`, instead of `component x should have correct prop y`.

I believe Enzyme can do a lot of things that React Testing Library does, however, I would recommend to at least steer away from `shallow` rendering. [It is not considered a good practice](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17321#issue-520251612)

I still haven't found a use case where Enzyme solved a problem that React Testing Library does not. But that doesn't mean it doesn't exist. It just means that RTL suits me well for now.